# How to calculate size per minute of MP4 file(MPEG4,H.264)?

Tags: c++, ios, bitrate

I've a .MP4 file. I know MP4 file has some attributes such as: general bitrate,file size.
Video: Max bitrate,min bitrate,avg bitrate,size
Audio: Max bitrate,min bitrate,avg bitrate,size
I want to get the size(or maximum size) per minutes from above attributes.
Can anyone help me?

Thank so much

Answer (score 1):

If the average bitrate is in bits per second (I think it is?), then you can get the "size per minute" like this:

```
 sizePerMin = 60 * avgBitRate
```

Which will be the size per minute in bits.  You can do similar for the max and min size per minute.

Comment: thanks,but some videos,we get the max and min bitrate are Undefined,only avg bitrate.I've tried with avg(or general bitrate of video,but it is wrong.I calcuted size/min = 5Mb,i write 5Mb but the media player can plays only 25seconds first.I think sizePerMin = 60*avgBitRate is wrong.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an online video-file-size calculator, you can specify your settings, and run it:

http://www.dr-lex.be/info-stuff/videocalc.html

Comment: Please avoid posting link-only answers

Comment: ...and yet this was an enormously useful answer (until that link goes dead). ;-)